# Find and replace a string in string with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I making certain words found in sentences bold. I don't understand much of regex, and this is not my code that works ALMOST.

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
        return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(\' + needle + \')(|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

This makes

- abundance -> Call it an **abundance** of caution, then.
- acquiesce ->  The end of a regime that **acquiesce**s to disorder!

However, it doesn't work when there's a special character before/around the word (the words don't become bold):

- apparatus -> Search him. - ...apparatus.
- auctioneer -> Well, I guess "auctioneer" could be kind of a cool thing to have on my resume.
- clatter -> (clattering)
- doorknob -> [doorknob rattles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of this part in your regex:

```
(^|\\s)
```

Which means that it is looking for search word at line start or after a whitespace. When there is no whitespace then this match will fail.

You can use **word boundary** if your search term is a **word** as shown in question and change your code to:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
   return input.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + needle, 'ig'), '<b>$&</b>');
}
```

PS: As per comments below it will match starting with given word. So `man` will match `mandate` but not `woman`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not always working. E.g. in case of disburse -> Which is why I disbursed the funds as you requested. Those cases are problematic where the context includes another form of the word  (-ed, -ing, -s etc.(

Comment: Well you haven't specified all the cases in question. But if those cases to be included then `return input.replace(new RegExp(needle, 'ig'), '<b>$&</b>');`  but it may match unwanted strings also e.g. `man` will match `mandate` or `woman`

Comment: Can you modify it so it matches words starting with the needle? It's okay if man matches mandate, but woman should not be matched. Also, can you clarify what do `\\b` and `ig` do?

Comment: Beautifully, thanks. Could you explain what do `\\bb` and `ig` do?

Comment: `\b` is for word boundary. Flag i is for ignore case and g is for global match.